# Are there "extremely non-commutative groups" $G\neq\{e\}$ such that $gh \neq hg$ for all $g,h\in G$ with $g\neq e$ and $h\notin \{e,g,g^{-1}\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's call a group $G\neq\{e\}$ "extremely non-commutative" if

$$ gh \neq hg~~\text{for all}~g\in G\setminus\{e\}~\text{and}~h\in G\setminus \{e,g,g^{-1}\}.$$

Do such groups exist? If so, do they have any interesting/important properties? Or can one always find at least one non-trivial pair of group elements which commute?

Comment: Well, if there is any element of order other than $2$ then $g\times g^{-1}=g^{-1}\times g$.  Of course, $e\times g=g\times e$ for all $g$ so you probably want to exclude $g,h=e$.

Comment: The identity element of $G$ commutes with every element of $G$.

Comment: Best exclude the identity too.

Comment: A nice problem for you to do is to classify groups where each element commutes with its powers and nothing else.

Comment: Changing the question after someone posts an answer to its original version is a very inappropriate behaviour.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am sorry if this came off as rude. This was obviously a flaw in my (admittedly naive) question, so making the question more precise seemed more reasonable than asking a new question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's not ideal, but in cases like this I'd say it's the answer that should not have been posted. Just posting the trivial counterexample 2 minutes after the question is posted makes a rather uninteresting Q/A, so IMO it's better to point it out in a comment (as you and others have done) to allow the asker to correct the question.

Comment: I think both the answer and the edit are inappropriate. :) @ArnaudD.

Comment: I would add that $g\neq e$, too. So, for $g,h\neq e$ you have $gh=hg$ if and only if $h=g$ or $h=g^{-1}.$

Comment: I think $S_3$ under this definitions is extremely non-commutative.

Comment: I agree that it's rude to change the question after someone's posted a correct answer; the good news is that it's perfectly OK to post a new, improved question (and to include, in the current question, as an addendum, a pointer to that new and improved question). I also think that there's a judgement to be made in providing trivial counterexamples -- in some cases, these are enough to satisfy the OP; in others (like this one), a comment asking "XYZ seems to be a counterexample; did you mean to ask ...?" might be more helpful, unless one is desperate to earn points. :)

Comment: If $G$ is a group, a subgroup $H$ is *self-sentralizing* if $C_G(H)\subseteq H$. In particular, this means that if $g\in G$, then $C_G(g)=\langle g\rangle$. *That’s* the definition you really want. So you are looking for groups in which every (cyclic) subgroup is self-centralizing.

Comment: (An even better definition would be that nontrivial elements have cyclic centralizers, because that allows elements to have non-prime orders). For finite groups, the only groups in which every nontrivial subgroup is self-centralizing are the cyclic groups of prime order and the nonabelian groups of order $pq$ with $p\lt q$ both prime, $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. For infinite groups, you get more examples, like Tarski monsters, but all locally finite groups with this property are in fact finite; but groups of exponent at most $3$ are nilpotent, so there are no examples with the restrictions you give.

Comment: The more natural requirement should be that h lies in the complement of the subgroup generated by g.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you. I have asked the corresponding question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282986

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that if $G$ is both non-commuative and "extremely non-commutative" then every non-trivial element has order two or three (as $g^2, g^3\in\{e, g, g^{-1}\}$). Note also that there *must* exist an element of order three, as groups where every element has order two are abelian. Also, if $G$ is finite then it must contain elements of both order two and three, as otherwise the centre of the group will be non-trivial. So, the smallest non-abelian group with elements of order both two and three is $S_3$....

**An example.**
The symmetric group $S_3$ is "extremely non-commutative". This is because centralisers of elements are cyclic: if two elements $x, y\in S_3$ commute then there exists an element $z\in S_3$ such that $z^i=x$ and $z^j=y$ (why?). The result then follows as all elements of $S_3$ have order two or three.

**Infinite examples?** There are no finitely generated, infinite examples of "extremely non-commutative" groups. To see this, note that (by the above discussion) $x^6=1$ for all $x\in G$. Therefore, if $G$ can be given by a finite generating set then $G$ is finite (this is non-trivial result, and the citation is M Hall Jr. *Solution of the Burnside Problem for Exponent Six*, Illinois J. of Math. 2 (1958), 764-786.) On the other hand, I see no immediate reason why there cannot be infinitely generated examples.

**Classification of finitely generated examples.**
The only finitely generated non-commutative, extremely non-commutative group is $S_3$. This is because, by the above, such a group is finite, and so by user10354138's answer, the group is $S_3$.

---

Its worth remarking that the OP seemed unsure of what the definition of "extremely non-commutative" should be. I feel that the "correct" definition is that $G$ is non-commutative and that non-trivial elements have cyclic centralisers. Then, for example, every torsion-free hyperbolic groups satisfies this more general condition.

Answer (score 6):

**Original Answer**: There are no nontrivial "extremely non-commutative group", because identity commutes with everything else.  Of course, the trivial group is "extremely non-commutative" because the condition is vacuous.

---

**Addendum**: With the restriction $g\neq e, h\notin\{e,g,g^{-1}\}$ the question is more interesting.  Certainly groups of order $\leq 3$ are extremely noncommutative (again, vacuously).  Assuming order of $G$ is at least 4, $g$ commutes with every $g^n$ so you need every $g$ has order $\leq 3$.  Since all groups of exponent 2 are abelian, you need some order 3 elements.  For exponent 3 there are no examples, because every finitely generated exponent 3 group is finite (this is due to Burnside, *On unsettled question in the theory of discontinuous groups*, Quart. J. Pure and Appl.  Math. 33 (1902), 230-238) and every finite $p$-group has nontrivial center.  So you want a mixing of order 2 and order 3 elements, and $S_3$ is an example.

In fact $S_3$ is the only example of a finite noncommutative extremely noncommutative group, because such $G$ is generated by a Sylow-2 and a Sylow-3.  The Sylow-2 can only be $C_2$ and the Sylow-3 can only be $C_3$ by the above discussion, so $G$ has order 6 and hence $\cong S_3$.

Comment: "Of exponent $2$" is a little unclear - I've never seen that phrase. It is not true that if $|G|$ is a power of $2,$ then $G$ is abelian. It is true that if $g^2=e$ for all $g\in G,$ then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the exponent of a group is defined to be the lcm of all orders.  "Groups of exponent $n$" is common enough expression.

Comment: A finite $p$-group will always have nontrivial center, so none of the nonabelian ones will work.

Comment: oops, corrected.

Comment: I just spotted the edit to your post -- my latest edit and yours combine to prove that $S_3$ is the only *finitely generated* non-commutative, extremely non-commutative group!

Comment: @user1729 Just restrict to a finite subset of the generators should be enough, no?  Every finite subset generates the same $S_3$ so you can't get anything bigger, because any element only uses finitely many of the generators.

Comment: Yeah, sure, that makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

The centralizer $C(g)$ of some $g\in G$ always contains $\langle{g}\rangle$. For a group in which any $g\not = 1$ has this minimal centralizer, take $G$ to be free.

Comment: As currently stated, free groups don't answer the question. All non-trivial elements must have order $2$ or $3$.

Comment: @user1729: Indeed, but the OP has changed a bit, and I thought that's what the poster was going for. (But if you take that interpretation, I think your remark about cyclic centralizers in hyperbolic groups is a much better answer. I guess the only drawback is that it's harder to prove; the proof I'm familiar with, at least, involves some results on the Rips complex and cohomology over $\mathbb{Q}$.)